# wpf user control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a wpf application that has a number of user controls defined.  For one of these controls (a login screen) I want to be able to hide the login user control and then display the registration user control.  In the code behind file for the login I have tried the following

```
Registration reg = new Registration();
reg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Is there a way to do this?  I have also read about a page object in reading upon wpf - is this a better way to go about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You've created it, but you haven't added it.

You need to add it to the parent UserControl or Window you want it displayed in.

Comment: For example you might have a StackPanel called RegistrationPanel and then you'd: RegistrationPanel.Content = reg;

Answer (score 1):

You could create both controls in a Grid or DockPanel or similar using XAML, and then set Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed to hide the individual controls.